# Syntax Error for React Redux Project when running npm start command

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax, redux

I am building a React-Redux Scoreboard project on GitHub and continue to run into an error in my terminal when I run "npm start".  The error says my Syntax for the files 'src/containers/player.js' and 'src/containers/Scoreboard.js' which code is posted below is incorrect. This is the link to my GitHub repo: [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Missybur/React-Redux-Example-Scoreboard-Project)  If anyone can help me resolve this error, I would really appreciate it!

**Player.js**

```
   import * as PlayerActionTypes from '../actiontypes/player';

const initialState = [
    {
      name: "Emmanuel",
      score: 31,
    },
    {
      name: "Arsenio",
      score: 35,
    },
      {
      name: "Melanie",
      score: 30,
    },
        {
      name: "Peter",
      score: 25,
    },
        {
      name: "Mani",
      score: 27,
    },
        {
      name: "Miguel",
      score: 29,
    },
        {
      name: "Jason",
      score: 22,
    },
        {
      name: "Missy",
      score: 28,
    },
];

export default function Player(state=initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case PlayerActionTypes.ADD_PLAYER:
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          name: action.name,
          score: 0
        }
      ];

    case PlayerActionTypes.REMOVE_PLAYER:
      return [
        ...state.slice(0, action.index),
        ...state.slice(action.index + 1)
      ];

    case PlayerActionTypes.UPDATE_PLAYER_SCORE:
      return state.map((player, index) => {
        if(index === action.index) {
          return {
            ...player,
            score: player.score + action.score
          };
        }
        return player;
      });

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Scoreboard.js:**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as PlayerActionCreators from '../actions/player';
import Player from '../components/Player';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import AddPlayerForm from '../components/AddPlayerForm';

class Scoreboard extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    players: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };

  render() {    
    const { dispatch, players } = this.props;
    const addPlayer = bindActionCreators(PlayerActionCreators.addPlayer, dispatch);
    const removePlayer = bindActionCreators(PlayerActionCreators.removePlayer, dispatch);
    const updatePlayerScore = bindActionCreators(PlayerActionCreators.updatePlayerScore, dispatch);

    const playerComponents = players.map((player, index) => (
      <Player 
        index={index}
        name={player.name}
        score={player.score}
        key={player.name}
        updatePlayerScore={updatePlayerScore}
        removePlayer={removePlayer}
      />
    ));

    return (
      <div className="scoreboard">
        <Header players={players} />
        <div className="players">
          { playerComponents }
        </div>
        <AddPlayerForm addPlayer={addPlayer} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => (
  {
    players: state
  }
);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Scoreboard);
```

[image: Terminal Errors]

Comment: Are you sure babel is set up correctly?

Comment: Hi Andrew, this is what I have in my .babelrc file:                                                       
 {
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"],
  "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
} ......Does that look correct to you?

Comment: You need this [transform-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)

Comment: Hi Arup Rakshit, so should I run: npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread ?

Comment: Arup Rakshit, I added '{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"],
  "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel", "transform-object-rest-spread"]
}' to my .babelrc file and that did not work.  Was that your intention of adding that line to my .babelrc file to resolve my error?

Answer (score 0):

In my Scoreboard.js file I should have typed "PropTypes" on line 1 instead of "Protypes" instead which was causing the error.